# Which data should I use to validate a model such as Decision Tree?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, validation

I am a little confused about this situation: I have a dataset for classification problem. It is divided into a training and a testing set. And I've used the training set to generate an artificial dataset from it (using an oversampling technique) to get a more balanced dataset (because the ratio between the two classes was very y unbalanced). I want to test my artificial dataset. So I want to use some classifiers such as Decision Tree, to compare with the orginal datasets.

The thing is that I am training the classifier with the artificial data, and then using that model I provide the testing dataset to get the prediction (as a final step: I get a confusion matrix); and also using the training dataset to predict and get another confusion matrix but in this case, as validation values. Is this approach OK? I am doing it well? should I training the model using the training dataset or the artificial?

Sorry if this is a little dum question, but I am new in this, and also I've seen only training and testing steps, and not the validation of models...

Thank you!!

Comment: I don't think you should be creating an artificial data set here.

Answer (score 2):

You have started out on the wrong foot IMHO.  Split sample validation requires huge sample sizes and so do single tree methods.  You may have miscast the entire problem as a classification problem instead of a prediction problem.   Use of oversampling means that you don't understand the statistical methods behind the method, and that you think that it is legal to make up data.  Any method that requires over/undersampling is defective.  Details are [here](http://fharrell.com/post/split-val) and [here](http://fharrell.com/post/classification).